# Symfony2-Doctrine2 inheritance persist not working properly

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I have a project in Symfony 2.3, using Doctrine ORM 2.3.4, and I'm using class inheritance:

a parent class

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="parent")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"child"="Child"})
 */
class Parent
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   private $id;

   public function getId()
   {
      return $this->id;
   }

   // other fields & methods
}
```

and a child one

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="child")
 */
class Child extends Parent
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    */
   private $id;

   public function getId()
   {
      return $this->id;
   }
}
```

The problem comes when I persist the child object, flush and then I try to retrieve the child id:

```
// ChildController::createAction

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$child = new Child();
// set child fields
$em->persist($child);
$em->flush();

$child->getId(); // <- not working
```

On the database the child row is saved correctly, and if I change the child method `getId`

```
public function getId()
{
   return parent::getId();
}
```

it works.

Can anyone please explain this to me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent entity needs to give visibility of it's properties to it's children.

Change your $id property visibility to "protected".

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit late, but maybe it helps others.

When you take a look at your table definition that Doctrine generated, you will see why it is this way. E.g. mine in postgres:

```
...
CONSTRAINT fk_5d9f75a1bf396750 FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES parent (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
...
```

As you can see, Doctrine uses for your child table id the id of the parent.
Like @John Cartwright said, make your $id in parent protected.
In addition to this define the getter only in the parent and everything works just fine.